# How to handle image visibility using MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have a image which I was able to bind with my Image property on XAML,the problem is, when I pop up my View I want that image stays invisible, and then when o click my button appears again so far I got this in m ViewModel :

private string imageSource;

```
public string ImageSource
{
    get { return imageSource; }
    set { imageSource = value; Notify("ImageSource"); }
}
public bool State { get { return false; }}


private Image visibleImage;

public Image VisibleImage
{
    get { return new Image {IsVisible = State,Source = ImageSource }; }
    set { visibleImage = value; Notify("VisibleImage"); Notify("State"); }
}
```

In my `BindingContext` the property IsVisible is set as false, but doesn't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your sample by avoiding to hold on to the `Image` reference in the view model at all. Modify your `State` flag like that:

```
private boolean _state;
public boolean State { 
    get { return _state; } 
    set { _state = value; Notify("State"); } 
}
```

In XAML declare the `Image` with its source and visibility binding:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" IsVisible="{Binding State}" />
```

Upon initialization of the view model set your `State` to `false`. The button click would then need to set the flag to `true` to make the image visible.